# where is the default exception resolver chain defined for a spring-boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a small test app with just spring-boot-starter-web defined in my pom.
The app is auto-configured through a `@SpringBootApplication` annotation.

Under such scenario, where is the chain of exception resolvers defined ?
(which file in which jar)

Note: I already found a resolver chain under `DispatcherServlet.properties` in the `spring-webmvc` indirect dependency jar, but since the `AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver` is now deprecated, I believe it's not the right place)

Thank you very much in advance for your feedback and your expertise

kbjp

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation, it looks like the handler chain is defined in the addDefaultHandlerExceptionResolvers method of WebMvcConfigurationSupport class inside the spring-webmvc jar.